# Are there any traces for evolution in modern humans over the last 100 years?

Tags: genetics

I ask that because I had a biology class and my teacher said something about a bone in the back of the head that apparently every male has, and for some reason, in the last 20-25 years, its started to fade away and so even though my father has the bone I don't. Or when I was still in high school, and I had to do X-rays for braces the doctor told me that I don't even have wisdom teeth? Are those traces of evolution or are they just random mutations?

Comment: Re: "*Are those traces of evolution or are they just random mutations?*" These two options are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Your biology teacher was quite misinformed if that is what they told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotting evolution over only 4 generations would be very difficult. You certainly wouldn't see an entire bone disappear in that timeframe, though it might be slightly smaller in average people today than it was several generations ago. Over the timescale you're describing, the only real option is epigenetic changes, which might not be permanent enough to "count" as evolution.